# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dclass

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, arm, linker-errors

I am trying to build ffmpeg on visual studio for ARM architecture. I run into following linker errors:

```
Error   58  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__dclass referenced in function mov_read_tkhd avformat.lib(mov.o)

Error   59  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__dclass avformat.lib(thp.o) 

Error   60  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__dclass avutil.lib(rational.o)

Error   61  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__dclass avutil.lib(eval.o)
```

What is __imp__dclass and where it is defined in Visual Studio / FFMPEG?

I get the following when I do "dumpbin /symbols mov.o"

```
22D 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __imp__dclass
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular issue was due to missing **isnan** and **isinf** methods in FFMPEG. There was a problem in bringing math.obj and float.obj dependencies.

Comment: This is helpful, as I'm seeing the same kind of thing. How did you identify which methods were missing?

Comment: Turns out it's `isinf` for me as well. How did you _resolve_ this?

Comment: FFmpeg configure would automatically do a check for isnan/isinf and mark a macro variable "HAVE_ISNAN" (I don't have code handy point out the exact variable name). If you search for it, you should be find an alternate implementation for isnan/isinf (workaround). However, in my case, it was due to compiler/visual studio configuration and it was not able to define it properly. At the end, I had to switch my co-workers virtual machine to get it fixed.

Comment: Yeah, my issue was a VS configuration thing as well, apparently. Even though they ship `isnan` and `isinf` as of VS2013, I couldn't get it to link properly. Alas.